# Titanium: Create fields like the ones in iPhone Contacts (Edit Mode) app

Tags: iphone, titanium, contacts, field, tableview

Note: The divider aka separator is the main point of this question. It must be visible.

Is there a way to create fields like the ones in the iPhone Contacts (Edit Contact Mode) app?

**I want to create a separator that separates the titleLabel from the textField.**
Like "  First Name  |  hinttext  "
Instead of "  First Name    hinttext  "

I think what I am trying to do is similar to this... except that I am using Titanium. Is there any way to do this using Titanium?
[How is iPhone Contact app's detail View implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528677/how-is-iphone-contact-apps-detail-view-implemented)

@MRT and anyone who knows:
How would you make the combined view such that it looks like this?

```
 ____________________
( Name  |   hinttext )
 --------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new **TableViewRow** and customize it.

You can put labels, fields, images, etc. in the TableViewRow.

Example:

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: "Name",
    width: 50,
    top: 5,
    bottom: 5,
    left: 5,
    font: {fontSize:10}
});
row.add(label);
```

Comment: I mean, how do I add that divider? I know how to add the name label and the text field. But how do I add the divider?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this really usefull to you

```
var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : 50,
    width: 150,
    top: 5,
    bottom: 5,
    left: 5,
    font: {fontSize:10}
});
var text1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    hintText : 'First Name',
    height : 50,
    width: 75,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    font: {fontSize:10}
});
var text2 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    hintText : 'hint text',
    height : 50,
    width: 75,
    top: 0,
    left: 75,
    font: {fontSize:10}
});

view1.add(text1);
view1.add(text2);
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the followup question? Thanks.

Comment: you have 2 way to do this.
check below :.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 way to do this.

1. take 2 TextField and adjust (top and left margin) and joint it. 
   or

1  Take 1 TextField
2. take 1 Label and its width 2 and height is equal to the textfield height.
3. TextField.add(lable1)

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
title : 'Window1',
backgroundColor : '#f00',
id    : 0,
});

var text1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
width : 150,
height : 50,
borderRadius : 9,
backgroundColor : '#fff',
top  : 50,
left : 20,
    });

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
width : 2,
height : 50,
top   : 0,
left  : 75,
});

text1.add(label1);
win1.add(text1);
win1.open();
```

Comment: How do you do the divider in the middle? That's actually the main issue in my question. +++

If I create a label, it would have rounded corners right? I only want rounded corners on the left and sharp corners on the right.

Comment: i write a demo full code u can copy and past and run on simulator. after this u tell me that. what happened and what u want okey...

Comment: 1) The code runs as expected for iPhone but there is no divider line. The main issue of my question is regarding the divider line. So the question hasnt been solved yet. 2) It's not working for Android. Android is always causing problems lol - the label doesn't even appear. I added text into the label and also made the width 50. Still no text.

Answer (score 0):

To add a vertical line

```
var vline = Ti.UI.createView({
    height: 44,
    width: 1,
    top: 0,
    left: 85,
    backgroundColor:'#CCC'
});

row.add(vline);
```

Comment: This line is not dynamic right? Do you know of a way to create a dynamic line that will follow the height of the textbox automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a TableViewRow and add labels to it. There is not a ready template to this rows. But you can create an *wrapper* to it, if you will use it a lot. For example:

```
var createTableViewRowWithTitleAndValue(title, value) {

    // TableViewRow
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
    });

    // Title
    row.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: title,
        left: 5,
        font: { fontWeight: "bold" }
    }));

    // Value
    row.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: value,
        right: 5,
        textAlign: "right"
    }));

}
```

Then, when you set data to TableView, instead you create a new TableViewRow, you create a new **tableViewRowWithTitleAndValue**, with *title* and *value* needed. For example:

```
rows.push(new createTableViewRowWithTitleAndValue("Foo", "Bar"));
```