# view contact info on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, contacts

Hi I want to create a button that, when pressed, will view a phone number on the iPhone. I don't know if this is possible, but if it is I'd love for someone to help me with this.
I dont have any code for it, so someone would need to help me from start to finish. Thanks

Comment: Please search first before asking the question.

Comment: What do you men by "view a phone number", you just want to display the number or something else.

Comment: have you read apple documentation for the same???  You should google firstly for any question before putting it on stack overflow to be a smart user.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the Apple Developer site that should get you started:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html

It goes over both how to integrate with the Address Book database, and how to just use an Address Book-like view for listing contact information.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/400-UI_Controllers/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1

Comment: user should be able to view and edit the contact

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528677/how-is-iphone-contact-apps-detail-view-implemented